# Select2 3.4.5 dont show optgroup if all options under it are selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Is there any way to remove the optgroup title if there are no options under it to select (all of them were already selected) ?

My code is:

```
formSelectElement.select2({
    placeholder: 'Type to search for a user...',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    query: query,
    multiple: true,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    maximumSelectionSize: formSelectElement.data('primary'),
    initSelection: setAssigneeInitSelection
}).on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    if (e.val == 0) {
        e.preventDefault()
        return;
    }
});
```

And the data is:

```
var data = {results: []};
var teams = {id: 0, text: 'Teams', children: [some children here]};
var users = {id: 0, text: 'Users', children: [some children here]};
data.results.push(teams);
data.results.push(users);
```

So what I basically want is after every option under Teams is selected, the Teams header should dissapear

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Please read [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example